# Parsing titles from Entrez search result using biopython

Tags: python, regex, biopython

I am trying to search for papers with specific words in the title using [`biopython`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython). More precisely, the word viral or virus in papers published between 2010 and 2015. Here is the code I have:

```
import re
from Bio import Medline

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed",  # database to search
                    term="2010[Date - Publication]:2015[Date - Publication]"
                    )
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()

pmid_list = record["IdList"] #list of records

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list, rettype="medline",     retmode="text")
records = Medline.parse(handle)

titles = [] # start with empty list of titles
for record in records:
    ti_list = record['TI'] #titles
    for title in ti_list:
        if title == "virus" and title not in titles: #searching viral/virus
        titles.append(title)

print('Publications with viral or virus in the title:')
for record in records:
    print(" ", title)
```

If I simply print(record['TI'], then I get a list of all titles in my search query. However, I'm not able to search the specific word. I think my mistake may be in the "if title == "virus" (because obviously no paper will be titled with that word alone).

I am pretty stuck. Is there a better way to be searching for this word in the titles of the papers I've queried?

Thanks.

Edit: Updated code with `re.search` (and still no luck)

```
r = re.compile(r"\bvir(al|us)\b")
titles = set()  # start with empty list of titles
for record in records:
    ti_list = record['TI']  # titles
    for title in ti_list:
        if r.search(title):  #
            titles.add(title)

print('Publications with viral or virus in the title:')
for record in records:
     print(" ", title)
```

New code:

```
import re
from Bio import Medline

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmid_list, rettype="medline", retmode="text", 
                       term="2010[Date - Publication]:2015[Date - Publication]")
titles = []
for record in Medline.parse(handle):
    for title in record['TI']:
        titles.append(title)
handle.close()
for title in titles:
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match substrings use *in* to see if any of the words are contained in the title:

```
words  = ("viral","virus")
if any(w in title for w in words) and title not in titles: #
```

But you seem to want to filter the records getting any record title that contains viral or virus:

```
st  = {"viral","virus"}

filtered_records = [ record for record in records if any(w in st for w in record['TI'] )]
```

If you want to match substrings and use a pattern then you actually need to make it a regex, `"vir(al|us)"` is just a string in your code:

```
import re

r = re.compile("vir(al|us)")
filtered_records = [record for record in records if any(r.search(w) for w in record['TI'])]
```

The regex in your own loop would go where your if is:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"vir(al|us)")
if r.search(title) and title not in titles: 
      .......
```

If you don't want viruses etc.. to match then use a word boundary for your regex:

```
r = re.compile(r"\bvir(al|us)\b")
```

You should also make titles a set which cannot have dupes, a working example using your own code:

```
r = re.compile(r"\bvir(al|us)\b")
titles = set()  # start with empty list of titles
for record in records:
    ti_list = record['TI']  # titles
    for title in ti_list:
        if r.search(title):  #
            titles.add(title)
```

Which can become a set comprehension:

```
r = re.compile(r"\bvir(al|us)\b")

titles = {title for record in records for title in record['TI']  if r.search(title)} # titles
```

Since `record['TI']` returns a string and not a list:

```
r = re.compile(r"\bvir(al|us)\b")
titles = set() 
for record in records:
    title = record['TI']  # title is a str not a list
    if r.search(title):  #
           titles.add(title)
```

Do the same with the set comp or any other example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. How would I fit the regex version of your answer into my code?

Comment: @user3723011, what are you trying to achieve? You are adding to a titles list but you don't seem to be using it. Also are you looking for substrings or exact matches?

Comment: My goal is to have an output that says 
`Publications with viral or virus in the title: 
[List of publications with viral or virus in the title]`. 

I'm trying to get exact matches.

Comment: @user3723011, then use the last regex

Comment: I tried doing that but I'm still getting a blank output.

`titles = [] # start with empty list of titles
for record in records:
    ti_list = record['TI'] #titles
    r = re.compile("vir(al|us)")
    if r.search(title) and title not in titles: 
        titles.append(title)`

To replace the second to last chunk in my code. Still no luck. Maybe I'm not adding it in correctly.

Comment: add a sample of what a  "title" looks like

Comment: Sure thing. If I do `for record in records:
    print(record['TI'])` then I get an output that looks like:

`[Reasoning madness. Interpretation delusion].
[French classical psychiatry: Interpretation delusion of Serieux and Capgras].`

Comment: So one string per list?

Comment: Hm, well I'd actually prefer the list to contain every title as a separate string.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, the last code snippet matches titles that contain viral or virus so if that does not work then they must not exists.

Comment: Ok I edited my OP to give a little more context. I am sure that papers exist that have viral or virus in the title.

Comment: This does exactly what the code in your edit is doing,  you need to print the titles and see what is happening as the code above will 100 percent work if you have strings containing either viral or virus

Comment: I'm not sure why it's still not working. I just edited the OP to put the latest code I've been running without any luck.

Comment: Print out each title in the lopmand add one to your question that actually includes either viral or virus

Comment: The first result in this web search (which should be outputting the same thing) has virus in the title: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Wilke+CO%5BAuthor%5D+AND+2010%5BDate+-+Publication%5D%3A2015%5BDate+-+Publication%5D

Comment: Add the print output to your question, that is what matters.

Comment: I don't think I follow what you're saying.

Comment: In the for loop. **for title in ti_list:** *print each title*  and show me the exact output where it contains virus or viral

Comment: I just added some new code. It spits out titles, but only letter by letter (not sure why). However, you can see that "virus" is in the first title.

Comment: Well then you don't have a list, you have strings. I will edit, this is why I asked you to print the titles.

Comment: First step is to always verify that you are getting what you think you are, python is an interpreted language so it is easy to add some  prints for debugging

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much. You helped me a ton. Sorry for all the confusion.